# Authenticate user after registration - MVC app and Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

How would I go about authenticating a user after registration within an MVC application that uses Azure Active Directory? We plan to have a Registration page for users, but what needs to be done to actually let the user access the rest of the MVC app with [Authorize] on controllers? We will be creating the account in Azure AD during registration

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at the [developer guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-developers-guide/) and the [samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?query=active-directory-dotnet)?

Comment: Yes, I've taken a look at those. I didn't see one for using MVC with and API and Azure all at once. Basically, my MVC app should be nothing but a client where my API drives everything, including login(returning token). What I want to do is make a call to the API (api/login) and have a token that I can then use to in MVC as if I were doing something like this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#web-browser-to-web-application

Comment: Hey Victor - who is your target audience here? Can anyone register for your app, or must they  already have an account with their company?

Comment: @dstrockis - yeah, anyone can register. I think the issue is that this scenario is not supported by AAD. I am going to play around with AAD B2C as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153903/turn-authenticationresult-into-mvc-session.

With that flavor of AD, my scenario is well supported and should be possible. I'll report back once I get a chance to try it

Comment: That was my very next comment :-) Please let us know what you think!

Comment: @dstrockis - so far, from the videos and these resources:

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview.aspx

It looks  great! BUT, any guess on when it will be production ready? Not just AD B2C but also :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Also, is there any chance a tutorial can be posted besides just the project on GitHub? Much appreciated it! The Azure Gods have really smiled upon me on this one.

Comment: Don't want to give out any dates on SO, sorry...  We don't have a hard date anyway.  There's some tutorials at aka.ms/aadb2c if you haven't found those yet