# Turn AuthenticationResult into MVC session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

### What?

I have an API that takes a username and password and can return an `AuthenticationResult`. I want to make use of that token in order to start a session within the MVC app. Here's the flow of thins:

1. User goes to MVC app
2. User gives password and username
3. MVC calls API and sends username and password
4. API returns token to MVC app

After step 4, what can I do to start a session within MVC.

Info on the scenario:

We want to leverage Azure Active Directory to keep all our user info there, but we want users to be able to register using any email, not just our domain. We plan to make an account for every user in AAD using a combination of their email and our domain(since account created in AAD have to belong to a domain). So if the user's email is *john@gmail.com*, AAD will store *johnatgmailcom@ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com*

### Why?

- We can't force a user to create an account using our domain.
- We don't want users to see the AAD login screen
- We don't want to store any sort of user account info in our DB
- We plan to leverage AAD in the future within an iOS/Android apps so having authentication outside the MVC app would allow for this

This is the POC code that we have in our API that authenticates a user login request coming from the MVC app:

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-ccccccccccccc/oauth2/token");
try
{
    UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(userCredendtials.Username, userCredendtials.Password);
    AuthenticationResult azureADToken = context.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net@" + "ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com", clientID, uc);
    return Ok(azureADToken);
}
catch
{
    // We didn't authenticate user, send not found - generic error, we can change this
    return NotFound();
}
```

We then check what the result of the API call was within the MVC app to respond accordingly. The $1,000,000 question is how can we start and mange the MVC session as if we were using something like ASP.Net Identity using the token???

We can modify the API and the MVC app as needed but we do have the rewuirement of letting users create their account with any email and to store their info on AAD. If this is totally on the wrong path, any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario you described is not supported and not recommended with Azure AD. If you want a white label experience, where uses can pick arbitrary usernames and you can fully customize the cred gathering page, please consider Azure AD B2C: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I need to implement! Thanks for the link.